# Programs do not compile in JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

We were given an assignment:

> Design a Ship, CargoShip and CruiseShip class being mindful of behavior of each. Demonstrate the classes in a program that has a Ship array. Assign various Ships, CruiseShip and CargoShip to the array elements.

`CargoShip` and `CruiseShip` are a child of `Ship` class.

Please tell me what is wrong with my code. My professor's comments: Programs do not compile, since you are not defining classes CruiseShip, CargoShip, but you are using them in the program.

I don't understand what he meant by "programs do not compile and that classes were not defined".

I would very much appreciate a feedback.

Below is my code:

**ShipDriver.java**

```
public class ShipDriver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Ship[] ships = new Ship[3];
        ships[0]= new Ship("Destroyer",1886);
        ships[1] = new CruiseShip("Small","Arethusa",2007,50,26,18,0,1);
        ships[2] = new CargoShip("Mærsk Mc-Kinney Møller",2013,1306,190,174500);

        System.out.println("SHIP LIST\n");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < ships.length;i++){
            System.out.println(ships[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Ship.java**

```
public class Ship{
    String ship;
    int yearBuilt;

    public Ship(String ship, int yearBuilt){
        this.ship = ship;
        this.yearBuilt = yearBuilt;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "SHIP\nShip Name: " + ship + 
                "\nBuilt: " + yearBuilt;
    }  
}
```

**CruiseShip.java**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CruiseShip extends Ship{
    String category;
    int passengers;
    int cabins;
    int cabinsWithBalconies;
    int swimmingPools;
    int restaurants;

    CruiseShip(String category, String ship, int yearBuilt, int passengers, int cabins, int cabinsWithBalconies, 
            int swimmingPools, int restaurants){
        super(ship, yearBuilt);
        this.category = category;
        this.passengers = passengers;
        this.cabins = cabins;
        this.cabinsWithBalconies = cabinsWithBalconies;
        this.swimmingPools = swimmingPools;
        this.restaurants = restaurants;
    }

    public String toString(){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        return "\nCRUISE SHIP\nCategory: " + category +
                "\nShip Name: " + ship + 
                "\nBuilt: " + yearBuilt +
                "\nPassengers: " + df.format(passengers) + 
                "\nNumber of Cabins: " + cabins +
                "\nNumber of Swimming Pools: " + swimmingPools +
                "\nNumber of Restaurants: " + restaurants;
    }
}
```

**CargoShip.java**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CargoShip extends Ship{
    int length, beam, maxCapacity;

    CargoShip(String ship, int yearBuilt, int length, int beam, int maxCapacity){
        super(ship, yearBuilt);
        this.length = length;
        this.beam = beam;
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    public String toString(){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        return "\nCARGO SHIP\nShip Name: " + ship + 
                "\nBuilt: " + yearBuilt +
                "\nLength Overall (ft): " + df.format(length) +
                "\nBeam (ft): " + beam +
                "\nGross Tonnage: " + df.format(maxCapacity);
    }
}

/** OUTPUT

SHIP LIST

SHIP
Ship Name: Destroyer
Built: 1886

CRUISE SHIP
Category: Small
Ship Name: Arethusa
Built: 2007
Passengers: 50
Number of Cabins: 26
Number of Swimming Pools: 0
Number of Restaurants: 1

CARGO SHIP
Ship Name: Mærsk Mc-Kinney Møller
Built: 2013
Length Overall (ft): 1,306
Beam (ft): 190
Gross Tonnage: 174,500

*/
```

Comment: i checked your code and it is working fine, seem like your professor had some issue with class or he did't provide all the classes while compiling.

Defining of class means creating class, as you have already created them with name CruiseShip and CargoShip

Comment: I didn't understand what he meant by not compiling as I believe my program runs. Thank you very much for your comment. I will talk to my professor.

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy? Where is the Ship class? Need to import it

Comment: public class Ship{
    String ship;
    int yearBuilt;

    public Ship(String ship, int yearBuilt){
        this.ship = ship;
        this.yearBuilt = yearBuilt;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "SHIP\nShip Name: " + ship + 
                "\nBuilt: " + yearBuilt;
    }  
}

Comment: You need to import it into the other .java files

Comment: Do you mean that my Ship class should not be in a separate java file?

Comment: @EdHeal he is using default package for all classes and all classes are in same folder he does't need  to import any of his class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shown here is perfect and running.
There is no chance for any compilation errors if all of the them are in the same folder.

I tried compiling your code and i got the output. A screenshot of the same is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Think your code is fine and there is no problem with it.

It is possible that your code is not working fine because packaging is not done properly. If they are in the same package or location then there is nothing wrong.

```
 If you put them in the same location then they will work fine and it is guaranteed. At max it might be possible your professor is wrong.
```